# Загрузка файлов на сервер php (zip/rar)

Tags: php, загрузка, zip, rar

Как правильно переделать этот код чтоб можно было загружать не картинки ,а .rar .zip архивы ?

Форма

```
    <form action='../upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input name='file[]' type='file' multiple='true' />
    <input type='submit' value='Загрузить скриншоты' />
</form>
```

И php

```
    <?php

$pic_weight = 950;
$pic_height = 535;

if (isset($_FILES))
{
  //пролистываем весь массив изображений по одному $_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v
  foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v)
  {
    //директория загрузки
    $uploaddir = "files/";
    //новое имя изображения
    $apend=date('YmdHis').rand(100,1000).'.png';
    //путь к новому изображению
    $uploadfile = "$uploaddir$apend";

    //Проверка расширений загружаемых изображений
    if($_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/png" ||
    $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/jpeg")
    {
      //черный список типов файлов
      $blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4", ".txt", ".zip", ".html");
      foreach ($blacklist as $item)
      {
        if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['file']['name'][$k]))
        {
          echo "Нельзя загружать скрипты.";
          exit;
        }
      }

      //перемещаем файл из временного хранилища
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], $uploadfile))
      {
        //получаем размеры файла
        $size = getimagesize($uploadfile);
        //проверяем размеры файла, если они нам подходят, то оставляем файл
        if ($size[0] < $pic_weight && $size[1] < $pic_height)
        {
          //.....код
          //я обычно заношу пути к изображениям в бд
          //.....код

          echo "<center><br>Файл загружен. ( http://upload.creamoo.ru/$uploadfile ) <- ваш путь к файлу.</center>";
        }
        //если размеры файла нам не подходят, то удаляем файл unlink($uploadfile);
        else
        {
          echo "<center><br>Размер пикселей превышает допустимые нормы (945 X 530) . </center>";
          unlink($uploadfile);
        }
      }
      else
        echo "<center><br>Файл не загружен, вернитесь и попробуйте ещё раз.</center>";
    }
    else
      echo "<center><br>Можно загружать только изображения в форматах jpg, jpeg и png.</center>";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно все картинки выгружать в папку, а потом эту папку архивировать. [Тут](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php) много полезной информации. Используйте ZipArchive (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7, PECL zip >= 1.1.0)

Простой пример:

```
$nameFile = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$download_folder = './files/';

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$fileconpress = $download_folder.$nameFile.".zip";

$conpress = $zip->open($fileconpress, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
if ($conpress === true)
{
    $zip->addFile($tmpName);
    $zip->close();
    echo $fileconpress."<br/>";
    echo "Успешно сохранилось! ";
}
else echo "Ошибка";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_FILES))
{

    foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v)
    {
     $uploaddir = "files/";
     $apend=date('YmdHis').rand(1000,9999);

     if ($_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "application/zip") { $apend .=".zip"; }
     elseif ($_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "application/x-rar-compressed") { $apend .=".rar"; }

     $uploadfile = "$uploaddir$apend";

      if($_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "application/zip" || $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "application/x-rar-compressed")
      {
           if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], $uploadfile)) {


                echo "<center><br>Файл загружен. ( http://upload.creamoo.ru/$uploadfile ) <- ваш путь к файлу.</center>";


          }
            else
                echo "<center><br>Файл не загружен, вернитесь и попробуйте ещё раз.</center>";
      }
       else
           echo "<center><br>Можно загружать только изображения в форматах zip и rar.</center>";
    }
}
```